# @Configurable, <context:spring-configured/>, Hibernate & @EntityListeners: listeners not getting injected

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, autowired, entitylisteners

Environment:  JDK 1.6, Maven 2.2.1, Hibernate 3.6.7.Final via Hibernate EntityManager, Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE.

I can't figure out why my the entity listener instances aren't getting injected by type with `@Autowired` dependencies, even though I've made sure to include `<context:spring-configured/>` in my application context and included a `depends-on="org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect` in my LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean definition.

The appropriate `@Entity` classes include `@EntityListeners({...})`, and the entity listener classes are annotated with `@Configurable`, and their dependencies are annotated with `@Autowired`.

In the log, I see the `internalBeanConfigurerAspect` being instantiated, I can see my listeners getting instantiated by Hibernate via reflection, but I never see the injection taking place, and then I get a NPE in the listener when the listener's injected dependencies get invoked.  I've tried every magical incantation & can't seem to find the right one.

Anyone have any ideas what I have to jiggle to trigger the `@Configurable` DI?

TIA,
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

[@Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-configurable-testing) support requires weaving using Aspectj - either compile time weaving or load time weaving should work. Can you confirm if your using aspectj weaving, if not that could be the reason why the @Configurable annotated beans are not being autowired in.